# Windows 8.1 start-up logo replaced with Toshiba logo after changing partition type to gpt and boot mode to UEFI mode

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows-8.1, bios

I have an Toshiba Satellite L850-1LL and I decide to install Windows 8.1 x64 to see how it

works.

First I've installed on CMS Mode and mbr disk partition style and there was logo of Win 8.1

Then I want it to try if it can go faster so I changed disk partition style from mbr to

gpt and Boot Mode in BIOS to UEFI mode. Now everything is going fine but without Windows

Logo.

I also uptade BIOS, successfully. How can I restore the Windows 8.1 logo back? Is it possible?

Comment: I enabled UEFI Mode

Comment: Are you talking about the boot animation?

Comment: At start-up I see logo of the manufacturer which is normal, but after few sec it should vanish an I would see Windows logo, but intsead I see only "Toshiba - Leading innovation" and circle of loading system

Comment: Does Windows boot up? if not, you may have to reinstall, as you changed quit a bit with the system.

Comment: Manufacturers are allowed to replace the Windows logo with their own logo. I think it's stored in the UEFI / BIOS so you can't replace it.

Comment: ok. so it will be like it is now, is it correct?

Comment: It may be stored in the SYSTEM partition

Comment: @EdG I don't think so. I replaced my HDD with a SSD and I have the Lenovo logo on my laptop.

Comment: @user2210761 I was thinking about changing my HDD with a SSD one but if the situation is the same as you pointed out I will have to reconsider it.

Comment: But then what would it do if you had Win7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal. The logo is stored inside the UEFI firmware and it used during UEFI boot. On my Dell I can get rid of it by enabling the Option `Load VGA Option ROM` in the UEFI settings. This disables the [GOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#GOP) of UEFI.